# Tomcat 8 Manager war deploy upload fails over SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, encryption, deployment

This is a weird one - and I've looked high and low for clues but not getting anywhere. Running Tomcat 8 / Java 8 on Solaris. NIO connector configured for SSL. Everything seemed to be working fine, but now deploying a war file via the manager fails on Firefox and Chrome. It still seems to work using IE 11 in an old emulation node. The different browsers give different complaints:
FF - Secure Connection Failed, Chrome - This site can’t be reached.
Everything else seems to work - you can log on to manager, the SSL connection looks properly configured you can browse to various manager pages, but the file upload deploy fails. I checked the manager log and errors to this request seem related to bufferCrypt and  NativeGCMCipher. (see stack trace below)
I've tried:
-Updating to latest JDK (u92) - Oracle had reported a buffer size determination issue in NativeGCMCipher that was fixed
-Tried setting larger buffers in the connector, namely socket.rxBufSize, socket.txBufSize, and socketBuffer
-Tried switching to BIO connector (thought this fixed this issue on another server)
But had no luck with any.

If anyone has any advice it would be appreciated. We can use IE for uploads or simple copy deploys, but I'm wary that this sign of a bigger issue that could bite us when we role out 25 apps on these servers.

Here's the stack trace from the manager log:

```
07-Jul-2016 13:44:12.597 INFO [http-nio-8086-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
07-Jul-2016 13:44:50.623 SEVERE [http-nio-8086-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [HTMLManager] in context with path [/manager] threw exception
 java.security.ProviderException: Could not determine buffer size
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:843)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2460)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:974)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:173)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:251)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:232)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:338)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:363)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:563)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:874)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2730)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3064)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.crypto.ShortBufferException: Output buffer must be (at least) 12272 bytes long
    at com.oracle.security.ucrypto.NativeGCMCipher.engineUpdate(NativeGCMCipher.java:266)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:828)
    ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The last lines of your post refer to the socket output buffer.

The [tomcat configuration page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) reads

> socketBuffer   The size (in bytes) of the buffer to be provided for
>   socket output buffering. -1 can be specified to disable the use of a
>   buffer. By default, a buffers of 9000 bytes will be used.

So I guess a first step would be to find your ssl connector in server.xml and add socketBuffer="12272" or a larger value.

This is also mentioned on [ibm's tomcat tuning page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-run-asf-tomcat-on-ibmi/) under tuning tomcat.

Comment: I had tried this, i.e. socketBuffer="12272", but the upload deploy still failed. I tried it again to be sure and uncovered further weirdness. When I try the upload deploy with firefox I receive no buffer errors, but when I try it with Chrome I do receive the buffer errors in the manager log.

Comment: Speaks further to the issue being browser related, but as to why has me stumped. I'm inclined to think the buffer error is a misleading or maybe unrelated error, but I don't have anything else to go on. I thought I might be able to fall back to the BIO connector, but it exhibits the same problem. I'm guessing it's something to do with the SSL set up. We are using internal certificates issued but our organization

Comment: and sslProtocol="TLS"

Comment: I am still looking at it, but I would like to ask if you tried a larger value than "12272"?

Comment: First time tried socket.txBufSize="64000" based on another post

Comment: I'm hitting out server directly and it's served on an alternate port - 8086. in the final configuration it will be fronted by a netscaler. when I use netscaler URL the file upload succeeds! This is in test so both the server and netscaler are configured with internally issued certs. Firefox complains in both cases with "Unknown Issuer" and I add the security exception. The manager gui works perfectly in both cases: status, complete status, etc., but fails for the upload when hitting the server directly. I have a suspicion its the way firefox is adding the exception.

Answer (score 0):

My system has the same issue. After a day searching, I found that oracle ucrypto JCE provider seem to be guilty.
So I've opened file jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/java.security and comment out the line

```
#security.provider.1=com.oracle.security.ucrypto.UcryptoProvider ${java.home}/lib/security/ucrypto-solaris.cfg
```

After restarting, my system work well.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip! I'll look into it. Do you think there is downside of disabling this provider? Does it fall back to some default ucrypto 
provider?

Comment: One other piece of info. I had doubled back with my developers who deploy more frequently a while back and they said they were no longer experiencing the issue. Some confirmed that again today. (we didn't change anything!) That makes me think that the issue was browser related and a browser update somewhere along the way fixed the issue for us.

Comment: When disable ucrypto, jdk will use SUN as JCE provider. Oracle document state that ucrypto work better in solaris than default java JCE provider (SUN). But in my situation, ucrypto seem to be buggy.